# Why does subtracting 1 from 0 using subl appear to result in 255 in x86 assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am playing with my first program in assembly, and I've got it to return status codes that can be displayed with `echo $?`. Out of curiosity, I tried to see what would happen if I returned a negative integer as my status code, like so:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

mov $1, %eax # set syscall to exit

mov $0, %ebx # set status code to 0
subl $1, %ebx # subtract 1 from it!


int $0x80
```

When I assemble and run my program I get the following output:

```
hc06@HC06:~$ echo $?
255
```

I'm a complete infant in assembly and I'm sure this is obvious behavior to the rest of you, but I'm very curious why this happens. Thanks!

Comment: because Linux exit status is an 8-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay, so when it gets the first 8 bits of -1  and reads that as an unsigned integer, the result is 255?

Comment: @AlejandroAlvarado - correct, the return value is only 8 bits, even though in C, the return value in main() is specified as an int. The return value is also only 8 bits for MSDOS and Windows, it is a legacy thing going back to some mini-computer system (PDP-11?).

Comment: Yup, 0 - 1 wraps around to the maximum unsigned value, with all the bits set.  Was that the part you were wondering about?  Plain old base 2 math.

Comment: note that [it's better to use xor to set a register to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/995714)